# Java BsonArray to json string

Tags: mongodb, mongo-java-driver

How can I convert a Java (/Scala) `BsonArray` to a json string?

If I have

```scala
val array = new BsonArray()
array.add(new BsonInt32(1))
array.add(new BsonInt32(2))
```

it would be nice if "array.toJson" gave me

```
"[1, 2]"
```

But `BsonArray` has no `toJson` method. So what could I do instead?

The real content of my array is more complex (nested documents) and I need to pretty-print it with indentations.

When I need to convert a `BsonDocument` I can call its `toJson` method

```scala
val doc = new BsonDocument()
// ..populate doc..
val pretty = JsonWriterSettings.builder().indent(true).build()
doc.toJson(pretty)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done in a hacky way by creating a temporary `BsonDocument` object with the `BsonArray` object as its value, converting the `BsonDocument` to JSON and then extracting out the part corresponding to the `BsonArray` from the output JSON string. Something like the below:

```java
public static String toJson(BsonArray bsonArray) {
    BsonDocument temp = new BsonDocument("x", bsonArray);
    String json = temp.toJson(JsonWriterSettings.builder().indent(true).build());

    return json.substring(9, json.length() - 1).stripTrailing();
}
```

You could also build the JSON yourself using a method like the below, but it might end up being a little too long and complicated(even before pretty print) if you need to handle all `BsonValue` types.

```java
public static String toJson(BsonArray bsonArray) {
    String json = null;

    if (null != bsonArray) {
        StringBuilder jsonBuilder = new StringBuilder("[");

        for (int index = 0; index < bsonArray.size(); index++) {
            BsonValue value = bsonArray.get(index);

            if (value instanceof BsonInt32) {
                jsonBuilder.append(((BsonInt32) value).getValue());
            } else if (value instanceof BsonDocument) {
                jsonBuilder.append(((BsonDocument) value).toJson());
            } else if (value instanceof BsonArray) {
                jsonBuilder.append(toJson((BsonArray)value));
            } else if (value instanceof BsonBoolean) {
                jsonBuilder.append(((BsonBoolean) value).getValue());
            } else if (value instanceof BsonString) {
                jsonBuilder.append('"');
                jsonBuilder.append(((BsonString) value).getValue());
                jsonBuilder.append('"');
            }
            // TODO Handle other required BsonValue data types like BsonInt64, BsonDouble, BsonTimestamp, etc

            if (index != bsonArray.size() - 1) {
                jsonBuilder.append(", ");
            }
        }

        jsonBuilder.append(']');
        json = jsonBuilder.toString();
    }

    return json;
}
```